# Windows 11 unable to format partition

Tags: windows-11, windows-installation, windows-installer

My laptop won’t boot due to a registry error BSoD, I’m now trying to reinstall windows 11.

I’m using install media on an external drive, and trying to format the internal SSD.

From the command prompt:
format c: /fs:NTFS

> Cannot Format. The volume is write protected.

Using diskpart I get similar errors when:

- trying to remove the read-only attribute.
- Clean the partition
- Delete the partition.

Mainly these errors are CRC failures.

WMIC get status reports OK on the disk, and the SSD is just over a year old.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: How old is the SSD?  Has it reached it's maximum lifetime writes by chance?

Comment: The SSD is around 13 months old, so I should it hasn’t reached maximum writes just yet

Comment: Age is a poor indicator of SSD life: frequent writes can do one in rapidly., e.g., https://www.laptopmag.com/news/windows-10-update-may-be-damaging-your-ssd-heres-how-to-stop-it

Comment: I agree with jar - try formatting using the GUI installer (setup.exe), like you normally would when installing from a Win11 ISO USB, and see if it works.  Have you tried this already, and that's why you're trying to format/clean the drive in cmd.exe (I'm assuming a console opened with SHIFT+F10)?  You could also try booting to something like Hirens or an Ubuntu USB - or even using a different computer to format the SSD.  Some motherboards have a feature built into the BIOS menu to erase an SSD.  Some SSD manufacturers also offer tools that can erase the drive.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried formatting it from the Windows Installation? I've faced the same problem too, but by just formatting it from the Windows Installation window, it works fine.

[image: "Where do you want to install Windows?" Picture (credit : Avocado - tenforums)]
Image credit: Avocado - https://tenforums.com